# I can't link two pages together in HTML.?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Ok, so I'm trying to create my first website and I've got all the HTML pages I want to link together, so when I click on "contact" for example, it opens that page, but I can't seem to make it work. I've looked everywhere and tried everything and nothing seems to do the trick.

Here's my code so you can see if i did something wrong:

```
    <header>
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>

    </header>
```

I've also tried this:

```
    <header>
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#index">Idex</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#more">More</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>

    </header>




<div id="contact" name="contact">
```

Hopefully you can help me! Thanks.

Comment: Are the files in the same directory? Are there any errors showing?

Comment: What’s the problem?

Comment: What do are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create a link that works between all my html documents, so when I click on "contact" for example, it takes me to that page.

Comment: That second one definitely won't work for what you're trying to do.  Those would reference anchor links on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st one code is right, but be sure that all files in same directory.

[image: files]

```
<html>
<body>  
<header>
    <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Please click accept icon ✅ on my answer if it solved your issue.